# How can I disable bash traces?

Tags: bash, shell

For any command that I execute in the terminal a comment like `+ command` appears. For example for `ls` it shows `+ ls --color=auto`.

Comment: Somehow you have set the debugger- `set -x` look for that entry in one of your shell startup files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `set +x` to disable debug. Thanks to @fd0 for the initial comment, that made this answer possible.

Answer (score 8):

Try typing `set +x` at your shell.  This should unset the `-x` option.